# Response Time for a web serivice in mule ESB?

Tags: mule, mule-esb

How do i get the **response time** of a POST request of web service in MULE ESB platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

you can use a variable to set the current time and then calculate the response time after you make your request or connector operation.

set current time in the response variable using dataweave

```
dw::util::Timer::currentMilliseconds()
```

calculate the response time later using a transformer where you set the result of the transformation to the responseTime

```
%dw 2.0
import dw::util::Timer
output application/json
---
Timer::currentMilliseconds() - vars.responseTime
```

Comment: Thanks for the above solution but does we have any inbuilt component/parameter in rest service which gives the response time by default when a request is processed?